# TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable while trying to decode base62

Tags: python, math, flask, base62

I'm trying to write a `decode base62` function, but python gives me the error:

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

This code works out perfectly outside of flask. but it doesn't work in flask.

The code is below : **EDITED:**

```
BASE_ALPH = tuple("0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz")
BASE_DICT = dict((c, v) for v, c in enumerate(BASE_ALPH))
BASE_LEN = len(BASE_ALPH)

def base62_decode(string):
    tnum = 0
    for char in str(string):
        tnum = tnum * BASE_LEN + BASE_DICT[char]
    return tnum


def base62_encode(num):
    if not num:
        return BASE_ALPH[0]
    if num<0:
        return False
    num = int(num)
    encoding = ""
    while num:
        num, rem = divmod(num, BASE_LEN)
        encoding = BASE_ALPH[rem] + encoding
    return encoding
```

This code works perfectly fine outside of flask, but gives me an error when I call it from my Flask App.

Comment: What are you passing in as `string` when you call the function `base62_decode`?

Comment: On which line are you getting that exception?

Comment: I'm not sure what line I'm getting the exception on, because Flask (web framework) isn't outputting a helpful traceback. I'm passing base62-encoded strings to base62_decode. It gives me the exception when I try to run base62_decode.

Comment: Are you *sure* you're passing in a string? Because this is the only (that I can find) situation where you'd get that particular error with this code. Also your code will run into an infinite loop if you pass it a negative number.

Comment: @Cydrobolt And if you try the code outside Flask?

Comment: Hmm, the code seems to work **perfectly fine** outside of flask

Answer (score 0):

Try to enforce converting to string, see if it enables you to run without errors, and then check your decoded output - I think at some point you have a string representing a number which is being converted internally by python, and that's where the error comes from:

```
def base62_decode(s):
    tnum = 0
    for char in str(s):
        tnum = tnum * BASE_LEN + BASE_DICT[char]
    return tnum
```

Note that this code assumes python 2; python 3 behaves differently when iterating over a string.

Comment: I'm still getting the `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable` error on the line `for char in len(str(string)):` - more specifically, I get `TypeError: 'int' object is not callable` when using `for char in string:`

Comment: @Cydrobolt Can you post the modified code snippet please.

Comment: Works outside of flask, gives exception when called from flask. I edited the code and posted it up.